# How to plus value with 1 When scroll to bottom and update into input form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to plus value with 1 When scroll to bottom page ?

First, Load page `index.php`

it's will show `1` (from `echo $_POST[page]`) and then scroll to bottom page it's will show `1` (from `echo $_POST[page]`)  and `1` (from `echo $_POST[page]`) and `1` (from `echo $_POST[page]`) ...

i want to apply this code for work like this

First, Load page `index.php`

it's will show `1` (from `echo $_POST[page]`) and then scroll to bottom page it's will plus `$_POST[page]` with 1 and update into input `id='page_number'` it's will show `2`  and `3` and `4` ...

How can i do that ?

index.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("#fid").submit(f1());
</script>


<form method="post" id="fid" action="Javascript:void(0);" >
    <input type='hidden' id='page_number' name='page' value='1'/>
</form>
<div id="demoajax">

<script>
function f1(){
    $('#demoajax').hide();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#demoajax').show();
            $('#demoajax').html(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
}
// on load page call function code //
$(document).ready(f1());
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){       
       var height = $('#demoajax').height();
       var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();       
        if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())){           
            //$('#demoajax').hide();
            //$('#protect_form_between_ajax_process').show();
            //$('#loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#fid').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
           $('#demoajax').append(data);
                    }
                });
            return false;
    }
    return false;   
    });
}); 
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?PHP
echo "PAGE ".$_POST[page];
?>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: on every AJAX requests you use the value from `$('#fid')` but you never change it, that's why you get all the times `1`. Also, beware of premature call invocation problem in lines `$(document).ready(f1());` and `$("#fid").submit(f1());` (see here for more information http://tobyho.com/2011/10/26/js-premature-invocation/)

Comment: pomeh , could you please give me some code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment the page number before each AJAX call:

**before**

```
if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#demoajax').append(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

**after**

```
if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())) {

    var currentPage = parseInt($('#page_number').val(), 10);
    currentPage = currentPage + 1;
    $('#page_number').val(currentPage);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#demoajax').append(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Beyond that, your code has some problems and could be written as follow:

```
<!-- Edit 1: HTML comes first, script come later -->
<!-- Edit 2: use real values in HTML attributes instead of JS code -->
<form method="post" id="fid" action="test.php" >
    <input type="hidden" id="page_number" name="page" value="1"/>
</form>

<!-- Edit 3: you had unclosed div tag -->
<div id="demoajax"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
// Edit 4: here, you can use only one script tag for all of your JS code
// Edit 5: declare functions first, use them later
// (you had the code $("#fid").submit(f1()); too early in the page)

function f1() {
    $('#demoajax').hide();

    var $form = $('#fid');

    $.ajax({
        // Edit 6: retrieve url and type parameter from the HTML form
        // this avoid hard-coded values
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            // Edit 7: use method chaining where you can
            $('#demoajax').show().html(data);
        }
    });
    // Edit 8: don't return false within event handler
}

// Edit 9: avoid premature call invocation problem
$("#fid").submit(f1);

// on load page call function code //
// Edit 10: avoid premature call invocation problem
$(document).ready(f1);

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // Edit 11: store and reuse jQuery variables
        var $window = $(window);
        var $demoajax = $('#demoajax');
        // Edit 12: remove unused variables scroll_top and height

        // Edit 13: use triple equal sign "===" instead of double equal "=="
        if(($window.scrollTop()+$window.height() === $(document).height())) {
            //$('#demoajax').hide();
            //$('#protect_form_between_ajax_process').show();
            //$('#loading').show();

            // ==============================
            // Edit 14: increment the counter
            var currentPage = parseInt($('#page_number').val(), 10);
            currentPage = currentPage + 1;
            $('#page_number').val(currentPage);
            // ==============================

            var $form = $('#fid');
            $.ajax({
                // Edit 15: same as above, avoid hard-coded values
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $demoajax.append(data);
                }
            });
            // Edit 16: remove unnecessary return statement here
        }

        // Edit 17: don't return false within event handler
    });

});
</script>
```

---

However, personally I would have write it using the module pattern, something like this:

```
var infiniteScrollLoader = function($container, $form, initialPageNumber) {

    var $window = $(window);
    var $document = $(document);
    var pageNumber = initialPageNumber;

    // this function crawls the content of the next page
    function requestNextPageContent() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: pageNumber
        });

        // when a request is made, increment page number automatically
        // avoid spaghetti code, use promise/deferred pattern
        request.then(incrementPageNumber);

        return request;
    }

    // use simple dedicated functions
    function incrementPageNumber() {
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
    }

    function showContainer() {
        $container.show();
    }
    function appendNextPageContent(data) {
        $container.append(data);
    }

    function showNextPage() {
        requestNextPageContent().then(appendNextPageContent);
    }

    function setPageNumber(pageNumber) {
        pageNumber = pageNumber;
    }

    function onScroll() {
        if(($window.scrollTop() + $window.height() === $document.height())) {
            showNextPage();
        }
    }

    function init() {
        $window.scroll(onScroll);

        $container.hide();

        // do initial request
        // this line should be self-explained and can be read as "text":
        // request the content of the next page, then show the container
        // then append the page content into the current page
        requestNextPageContent()
            .then(showContainer)
            .then(appendNextPageContent);
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        showNextPage: showNextPage,
        setPageNumber: setPageNumber
    };
};

// init and don't do anything else
infiniteScrollLoader.init( $('#demoajax'), $('#fid'), 1 );

// or use it programatically
infiniteScrollLoader.showNextPage(); // show page 2
infiniteScrollLoader.showNextPage(); // show page 3

infiniteScrollLoader.setPageNumber(6);
infiniteScrollLoader.showNextPage(); // show page 6
```